# SQL pulling related people

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to pull a table of people ages 64-80 and their associated family members.

For instance a family with no members aged 64-80 would not be pulled.  But a family containing 1 or more people aged 64-80 the entire family would be pulled.  And every family has a unique family code.

The table would look something like this:

[image: Resulting Table]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: I am surprised you have posted no query of your own. Have you not been able to come up with anything yourself? Not even getting the people in the given age range? Really nothing? You should come here *after* trying to write the query yourself. Then tell us where exactly you are stuck and we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to pull out all members of families that have at least one person whose age is between 64 and 80:

```
select f.*
from families f
where exists (
    select 1 
    from families f1 
    where f1.family_code = f.family_code and f1.age between 64 and 80
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(family_code, age)`.

In MySQL 8.0, you could use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select f.*, max(age between 64 and 80) over(partition by family_code) to_keep
    from families f
) t
where to_keep
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from tablename
where family_code in (select family_code from tablename where age between 64 and 80)
```